# Unexplained Vaadin error

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin

I'm trying to do a simple test where my Vaadin program will simply connect to a MS SQL Server database and retrieve some data. No big deal, except Vaadin wants to make it a big deal.

I don't know what's happened, but I'm now at a point where no matter what changes I make to my `VaadinConnManager` class, I get the *exact same* error message ("Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'") at the *exact same* line number, even if that line number *has nothing in it*. It's like the program is *stuck* on a particular revision and won't accept any other changes I make.

I think it's at least partially related to this odd error I'm getting in Eclipse. Here's what it looks like:

[image: Very odd error icons]

I've circled the two icons that are relevant. Usually the "red X" icon means that there is an error in the program, typically in one of the `.java` source files. But as you can see, there is no such error in any of my source files. There also appears to be a clipped exclamation point in the "Java Resources" folder. I think that small globe icon is just hiding the top half of it, which is why it looks like a red hourglass. instead of a red exclamation point.

Eclipse is of no help in telling me what these errors are. Or, at least, I can not figure it out. Admittedly, I am still learning Eclipse as I go, so it's entirely possible that I just don't know where to look to get an explanation for these red marks.

### Edit

I am pasting my code from the two `.java` files that are relevant in that screenshot above, as well as the error stacktrace.

**VaadinsqltestUI.java:**

```
package info.chrismcgee.sky.vaadinsqltest;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import info.chrismcgee.sky.vaadinsqltest.dbutil.ConnectionManager;
import info.chrismcgee.sky.vaadinsqltest.dbutil.VaadinConnManager;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Theme("vaadinsqltest")
public class VaadinsqltestUI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = VaadinsqltestUI.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        setContent(layout);

        Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
//              try {
//                  ConnectionManager connMan = new ConnectionManager();
                    SQLContainer container = VaadinConnManager.getJobs();
/*              } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*/
                layout.addComponent(new Label("Thank you for clicking"));
            }
        });
        layout.addComponent(button);
    }

}
```

**VaadinConnManager.java:**

```
package info.chrismcgee.sky.vaadinsqltest.dbutil;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer;
import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.connection.JDBCConnectionPool;
import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.connection.SimpleJDBCConnectionPool;
import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.FreeformQuery;
import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.TableQuery;
import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.generator.MSSQLGenerator;

public class VaadinConnManager {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(VaadinConnManager.class.getName());

    private static final String USERNAME = "web";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "web";
    private static final String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.248;databaseName=job_orders_2014";

    public VaadinConnManager() {
        }

    public static SQLContainer getJobs() {

        JDBCConnectionPool pool = null;
//      SQLContainer container;

        try {
            pool = new SimpleJDBCConnectionPool("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD, 2, 5);
            System.out.println("Connected!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
/*  
//      MSSQLGenerator generator = new MSSQLGenerator();
//      TableQuery tq = new TableQuery("Job", pool, generator);
//      tq.setVersionColumn("proof_spec_date");

//      FreeformQuery query = new FreeformQuery("SELECT * FROM Job AS j JOIN OrderDetail AS o ON j.job_id = o.order_id", pool, "job_id");
        FreeformQuery query = new FreeformQuery("SELECT * FROM Job", pool, "job_id");

        try {
            container = new SQLContainer(query);
            return container;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }*/

        return null;
    }

}
```

**stack trace:**

```
Apr 08, 2015 3:14:01 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Atmosphere is using async support: org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport running under container: Apache Tomcat/8.0.18 using javax.servlet/3.0 and jsr356/WebSocket API
Apr 08, 2015 3:14:01 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Atmosphere Framework 2.2.4.vaadin5 started.
Apr 08, 2015 3:14:01 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework interceptor
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor  Track Message Size Interceptor using | with priority BEFORE_DEFAULT 
Connected!
Apr 08, 2015 3:14:06 PM com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer getPropertyIds
WARNING: Failed to fetch property ids, rolling back
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:285)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.TableQuery.executeQuery(TableQuery.java:529)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.TableQuery.getResults(TableQuery.java:252)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer.getPropertyIds(SQLContainer.java:1194)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer.<init>(SQLContainer.java:134)
    at info.chrismcgee.sky.vaadinsqltest.dbutil.VaadinConnManager.getJobs(VaadinConnManager.java:38)
    at info.chrismcgee.sky.vaadinsqltest.VaadinsqltestUI$1.buttonClick(VaadinsqltestUI.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:977)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:393)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:168)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:291)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:184)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:92)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1408)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:350)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.
```

Line 9 shows the "property ids" warning, and the following line is the exception itself. Further down, on line 24, you'll see where in my class that the error occurred. Notice the line number: 38. If you'll see in my source code above, line 38 contains a commented-out line. And if I add more blank lines or move things around a bit, *the error stays on line number 38.*

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message when trying to open a table in Derby database.
The reason for my problem (SQLException) was that Derby doesn't understand the SQL statement

> SELECT * FROM .... LIMIT 20, 40;

which Vaadin needs to to fetch only the rows with numbers 20 to 40 (in this example) for their efficient paging / lazy loading  when showing a next page of rows in a Grid via a
    com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.TableQuery

The limit clause is generated inside

```
com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.generator.DefaultSQLGenerator.generateLimits(StringBuffer, int, int)
```

Actually Vaadin has a specialized class for MS-SQL-server - so it should work:
     com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.generator.MSSQLGenerator

(You can open the source via Eclipse Explorer >Libraries> Ivy > vaadin-server-7.4.0-sources.jar >  .. package.. )

Comment: Right. I didn't post my code earlier, but I am doing so now by editing my original post. Have a look at that code and you'll see that I did, indeed, use the MSSQLGenerator for that TableQuery. However, all of the references to TableQuery are commented out, anyway, as I switched to using FreeformQuery. But when the code is run, errors occur referencing line number 38, which is commented out by now.

I also made another project, duplicating this one to the last detail, and it works just fine. Makes no sense. It must have something to do with Eclipse.